# why my password accept in small and capital letters

Tags: php, validation, password-encryption

I created a validation for login where login_id and password is correct then it will redirect to another page my code is also working for validation. But I found a bugs that is if I give password in capital letters it is also accepting, while my password is in small letters. Why does it accept it?

```
<?php

//include('connection.php');
if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
    session_start();
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "school");
    echo $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //$sql="select * from login where username='$username' and password='$password'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from login where username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."' LIMIT 1");
    //$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if ($count > 0) {
        echo $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        header("location:Dashboard.php");
    } else {
        //header("location:Login.php");
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <strong>username and password wrong!!!.</strong>
    </div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your password in database, how it is inserted? Perhaps password is inserted in lowercase.

Comment: firstly password do not save directly security reason.

Comment: @AnthonyB my password is in lowercase

Comment: Do not save passwords in a DB or any permanent storage. Also just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force. Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you are not using case sensitive charset in MySQL. Either change your MySQL table charset or select the password from database and compare it using PHP.

Comment: Anyway,  as others suggested,  you should definitely use Bcrypt to hash your passwords.  Storing it as plaintext is an extremely bad idea :-)